# Code coloring in comment is not working

Tags: bug, status-bydesign, comments, code

I just observed that when I post a comment containing a piece of code, the code is not colored as it is in answers and questions. Here is a screenshot:

[image]

In the above screenshot, I just posted a comment as a test containing some code on my own question. e.g In the post, the strings are colored red but in the comment there is no coloring.

Comment: Example:  `abc="Hello world";`

Comment: I think that's by design.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Comments have never had syntax highlighting.

Comments are far from ideal for sharing code, since they cannot contain newlines. This makes syntax highlighting less relevant.

Also, code between backticks (``) has never had syntax highlighting. Code needs to be on a separate line, indented by 4 spaces, to have syntax highlighting. This is not possible in comments.

It's unlikely syntax highlighting will ever be added for comments, but if you can make a good case for it, you could open a [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) explaining the advantages of syntax highlighting in comments and discuss why it needs to be added.

Comment: To highlight code dumps in a comment: [`function createRandomPassword() { 

    $chars = "abcdefghijkmnopqrstuvwxyz023456789"; 
    srand((double)microtime()*1000000); 
    $i = 0; 
    $pass = '' ; 

    while ($i <= 7) { 
        $num = rand() % 33; 
        $tmp = substr($chars, $num, 1); 
        $pass = $pass . $tmp; 
        $i++; 
    } 

    return $pass; 

} `](https://stackoverflow.com/a/4571013/2263631) - It really doesn't look pretty and I doubt adding colours would help.